# Populate an array and then add a $watch to refresh list view angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a controller that looks something like this:

(function () {
    "use strict";

```
angular.module("app")
    .controller("postsController", postsController);

function postsController($scope, $http, $uibModal, PostService) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.posts = [];

    PostService.getPosts()
        .then(function (p) {
            $scope.posts = p.data;
        }, function (error) {
            vm.errorMessage = "Failed to load data: " + error;
        });

    $scope.$watchCollection('posts', function(newPosts, oldPosts) {
        PostService.getPosts();
    });
}
})();
```

The original data is pulled from the service and the posts array is populated properly.  However, I am have trouble having the view refreshed if data in the array has changed.  Either nothing happens on the view, or I am seeing an infinite loop with the $watch.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: there are a few issues here with this.  The first is that your `$watchCollection` calls the `getPosts` async method but then doesn't do anything with the data.  Also, you are mixing `$scope` and ControllerAs in the same controller, which can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

**Why** get infinite loop:

1. `$scope.$watchCollection('posts',function(){...})` watched your `post` array, when you refresh your view and `post` changed, **watch listener triggered**.
2. Then listener do `PostService.getPosts();`, resolve with `$scope.posts = p.data;`, this also change the `post` ( more: `post` been set back to data from backend, that's why nothing changed in your view), then **watch listener triggered** again. Then do `PostService.getPosts();` again, then again and again.
3. So you get a infinite loop.